# PIG - Can I coarse the result fs -ls into a tuple?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I'm new to pig.

In a pig script I can do something like:

```
fs -ls
```

which returns:

```
drwx------   - user group          0 2013-08-28 00:00 .Trash
drwx------   - user group          0 2013-08-02 19:19 .staging
...
...
...
```

Is there a way I can coarse the result of the `fs -ls` into a tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Java jar you can do such things very easily :
First you should create sequence file out of directory.
And then in the loader you should put code like below.
Then load the sequence file using this loader and the result will be as expected.

In getNext method (of Loader) you should write code like this according to your purpose

```
    ProcessBuilder scanProcess = new ProcessBuilder("strings",file_name);
    final Process process = scanProcess.start();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line,resLine="";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(!line.isEmpty())
        {
            resLine += line;
        }
    }
    protoTuple.add(resLine);
    return tupleFactory.newTuple(protoTuple);
```

In resLine result of execution of command will be stored.
For passing command line arguments you can explore ProcessBuilder and Process more

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but now that i know more about pig, I do believe this to be the correct approach.